Showing that meromorphic functions on compact Riemann surfaces can be extended to holomorphic functions
I have been reading through Evan Chen's "Napkin" (basically a concise overview of many higher math topics). In the Riemann surfaces chapter, the author leaves it as an exercise to show that if "$X$ is a Riemann surface, and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a meromorphic function, we can define a holomorphic extension $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ of $f$," where $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ is the Riemann sphere.

However, I am

i) unsure how to use the hint about "reparametrizing by $t = \frac{1}z$."
ii) unable to construct even a Taylor Series expansion around $0$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}x$

Any insights on either point would be deeply appreciated :)

Just have to say, $\mathbb C^\infty$ is a terrible notation for complex projective 1-space... a.k.a. "the Riemann sphere"...

What is his definition of "meromorphic"? The claim is false for the usual definition.

@MoisheKohan I am a bit slow. With which definition is this false?

Meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ is one which is holomorpic everywhere except for a discrete closed subset of poles. Thus, every entire function is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$. I suspect that by a Riemann surface the author means a compact one, then everything works. @SeverinSchraven

@MoisheKohan I am a bit confused. Why is that an issue? Isn't regularity a local question? If I pass to a chart around a pole on the Riemannian surface and pick a chart around infinity for the Riemann sphere, I'll get an analytic function (away from the pole) and the at the location of the pole I will converge to zero (thus by the extension theorem the map is analytic everywhere). Probably it's too early and I'm missing something basic.

Let me first recall the definition of an analytic function. Let $(X, \Phi), (Y, \Psi)$  be analytic manifolds, then a continuous function $g:X \to Y$ is said to be analytic at point $x \in X$, if for any chart $(V, \psi) \in \Psi$ which contains $g(x)$, there is a chart $(U, \phi) \in \Phi$ which contains $x$, such that $g(U) \subset V$ and $ \psi \circ g \circ \phi^{-1}$ is analytic on $U$.
Let now $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ be meromorphic, $Y = \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ is the Riemann sphere, $g:X \to Y$ is the extension of $f$ and $x \in X$ is a pole. Take $(V, \psi) \in \Psi$ with $V = \mathbb{C}^{\infty}\backslash\{0\}$ and $\psi(x) =  x^{-1}, \psi(\infty) = 0$, and take $(U, \phi)\in \Phi$ containing $x$ and such that $g(U) \subset V$. We have $\psi \circ g \circ \phi^{-1}$ is being analytic on $U\backslash\{x\}$ and having removable singularity at $x$, thus $\psi \circ g \circ \phi^{-1}$ is analytic on $U$, so $g$ is analytic at $x$.

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Sph}{\widehat{\Cpx}}$There are more layers to this onion that (my) initial reading suggested:

What it means for a mapping to the projective line to be holomorphic when it takes the value $\infty$, and what does this have to do with $1/z$?
What is meant by a meromorphic function?
What is meant by extension?

Since these resulted from successive peeling, let's take them in reverse order.
[3.] The term "extension" refers to making the domain larger. Here, however, there is a conceptual wrinkle hidden in the notation: We speak of "a meromorphic function $f:X \to \Cpx$," but if we're literal about "mappings," the domain of $f$ is not $X$; it's the set $X_{0}$ consisting of $X$ with the poles of $f$ removed.
Here, at risk of pedantry, the term extension refers to enlarging the domain of $\Sph$-valued maps from $X_{0}$ (which depends on $f$) to $X$. Since we're assuming $f$ is meromorphic on $X$, the conclusion holds as stated.
This scrutiny is not idle, however: I do not view $g$ as an "extension" of $f$, but as a reinterpretation of $f$ where we view a pole as "a point where the value is (literally) $\infty$." To the contrary, if $f:X \to \Sph$ is a meromorphic function, the term "extension" to a geometer (thinking of myself) is prone to suggest a map defined on a compact Riemann surface $\widehat{X}$ containing $X$ as a dense subset. As noted correctly in the comments, an extension of a meromorphic function in this sense need not be meromorphic. For example, $\exp$ is entire (holomorphic, hence meromorphic) on $\Cpx$, but does not have a pole at $\infty$, so does not extend meromorphically to $\Sph$.
If I were tasked with editing the question, it might read (more ponderously, but perhaps in ways that clarify the aims), "Let $X$ be a connected Riemann surface, $f$ a meromorphic function on $X$, $P$ the (discrete, see below) set of poles of $f$, and $X_{0} = X\setminus P$ the (dense, connected) set of points where $f$ is holomorphic, so that the restriction $f:X_{0} \to \Cpx$ is holomorphic. By viewing $\Cpx$ as a subset of the sphere $\Sph$, we may view the restriction of $f$ as a holomorphic map $f:X_{0} \to \Sph$. Show that if we define $g(p) = \infty$ for each pole $p$ of $f$, then the mapping $g:X \to \Sph$

Extends $f:X_{0} \to \Sph$, and
Is holomorphic even at poles of $f$."

[2.] To me there is Very Little Distinction between

A meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $X$, and
A holomorphic map from $X$ to $\Sph$.

If pressed, I'd clarify that a "meromorphic function" should not be identically $\infty$, while a "holomorphic map to the sphere" certainly could be. (Tangentially, if we're speaking of higher-dimensional domains, there is an unavoidable issue of indeterminacy sets, as for the meromorphic "function" $f(z, w) = z/w$ at $(0, 0)$. When we work in one variable, we can always avoid $0/0$ by canceling powers.)
[1.] So what was Chen getting at? Andrey's (+1) answer addresses the technicalities. To phrase things a bit more geometrically, the basic ideas are

We may view inversion, $z \mapsto 1/z$, as a holomorphic map from the sphere to itself with the understanding that $1/\infty = 0$ (not controversial to most calculus students) and $1/0 = \infty$ (generally alarming to calculus students and others, but justifiable here because we're looking at the one-point compactification of $\Cpx$). Under the usual stereographic projection to the unit sphere in real three-space, inversion is the half-turn about the axis through $\pm1$, a.k.a., $(\pm1, 0, 0)$.
If we want to examine "what a function does at infinity" we can perform inversion in the domain and see what happens at $0$. Algebraically, we substitute $t = 1/z$ or (equivalently) $z = 1/t$ and treat $t$ as a respectable complex variable. For example, the meromorphic function
$$
f(z) = \frac{2z}{1 + z^{2}}
$$
transforms into
\begin{align*}
  g(t) &= f(1/t) \\
  &= \frac{2/t}{1 + 1/t^{2}} \\
  &= \frac{2/t}{(1/t^{2})(t^{2} + 1)} \\
  &= \frac{2t}{t^{2} + 1},
\end{align*}
which not only has a zero at $t = 0$ (i.e., at $z = \infty$), but is equal to $f(t)$, i.e., is invariant under inversion.

